# Can Terracotta let peers negotiate who is master?

Tags: java, redundancy, terracotta, peer

I have a need for multiple peer processes (for redundancy), where only one should ever be actively processing. I know that Terracotta can help with master -> slave relationships, but can it help in this situation too? Can it be used to let the peers negotiate who is actively processing (and then renegotiate when the active peer dies)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cluster Events](http://www.terracotta.org/confluence/display/docs/Cluster+Events) to achieve this.

The currently active node could be a simple clustered root pointing to one of the nodes. If this node leaves, the others could renegotiate.

Comment: That looks promising. Will do some prototyping. Thank you.